# crossed random effects in nonlinear mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nonlinear, crossed-random-effects

I am a beginner in mixed effects modeling and am trying to find some useful code to solve my current problem. Specifically, I'm having some problems with model fitting. I'm looking for a representation of the cross-structure in a nonlinear mixed-effects model. I have found how it is solved in linear models (e.g., (1|species) + (1|plot)), however, the expression in nonlinear is confusing.

I tried to solve it using the pdBlocked function and the pdIdent function, but it failed.

My data structure is roughly as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
species_names <- paste0("Species", 1:15)
study <- sample(1:10, 500, replace = TRUE)
species <- sample(species_names, 500, replace = TRUE)
X <- runif(500, min = 1, max = 10)
Y <- X^2 + rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 5)
Z <- Y + rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 2)
Z <- 0.8 * Y + 0.2 * Z
dataset <- data.frame(Study = study, Species = species, X = X, Y = Y, Z = Z)
head(dataset)
```

That's all. Please don't hesitate to let me know if you're confused by my description and thus your judgment.

Thanks in advance for reading and answering!

Thank you very much for your enthusiastic comments! Also apologize for my lengthy comment. I think I understand what you mean, and I'll describe my problem gradually from here. As with the example I used above, my dataset presents a similar structure to it.

You can think of my dataset as a study and species relationship. Specifically, a species can exist in more than one study, and there can be more than one species within a study. At this point, studies and species are in a crossed relationship (rather than nested).

The rest is as described above, and I was unable to find a function (or package) that solves for this non-linear crossed relationship. I tried several approaches (see comments below), but none of them provided the desired result.

Concerned that my lack of description may have led to your misunderstanding, I've regenerated a more relevant dataset for reference. Thanks again for your interest and comments!

Comment: Welcome !!! Please provide the code you are using to fit the model (you can edit the question and add it)

Comment: Given the nonlinear form of the base model, I first considered the use of the nlme function to fit a mixed model with crossed structure (species and plots).
 `library (nlme)
head(data)
model1 <- nlme(Y~a*X^b,start = c(a=1,b=0.5),fixed = a+b~1,random = list(species=(a~1),plot_id=(b~1)),data=data)
summary(model1)`
However, I note that this structure is **nested** rather than **crossed**.

Comment: I then noticed a new method. The code is as follows:
  `power_function <- function(X,b0,b1) {
  Y <- (b0)*X^(b1)
  return(Y)
}
m1 <- lmer(Y~power_function(X,1,0.01)+(1|species)+(1|plot_id),
           data=data)
summary(m1)`  
This seems to solve my problem, but I can't add new variables. In other words, I can't give parameter estimates for the other covariates.  For example, if I now want to add a new variable A to the base model, how do I test for random effects of species or sample plots on A, and how do I obtain parameter estimates for A?

Comment: Please edit the model code into your question :)

Comment: OK, so `lme` (from the `nlme` package) does *not* support crossed random effects (though there can be some ways around it, but it's not straightforward). However. `lmer` (from the `lme4` package) handles crossed random effects very well. To help you further, more information is needed - please can you describe the study, and the data structure, and let us know your research question(s). Please don't add long comments with more detail. Instead please edit the original question instead (just choose the  "Edit" link just below the tags of the question).